# DNS leak with Shrew Soft VPN client on Windows 10

Tags: networking, vpn, dns

I am using the [Shrew Soft VPN client v2.2.2](https://www.shrew.net/software) to connect to a remote network. Everything works fine, except that I am experiencing a DNS leak according to https://dnsleaktest.com/.

In the VPN client, I already checked to use the DNS servers provided by the VPN server:

[image]

I also checked to *Obtain Topology Automatically or Tunnel All*:

[image]

According to https://dnsleaktest.com/ both DNS servers are used: the local one and the remote one (VPN). So some kind of load balancing occurs. Using `Get-DnsClientServerAddress` in PowerShell, I can confirm that Windows is aware of both DNS servers (local and remote). The local DNS servers are received from the physical NIC and the remote DNS servers are received from the virtual Shrew Soft NIC. So I am quite sure, that load balancing is occuring, which is very undesirable in this scenario.

Is there anything I can configure comfortably to use the local DNS servers when *not connected* to a VPN and to only use the VPN DNS servers when *connected* to a VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

Apply the highest priority (lowest metric value) to your VPN interface in comparison to other interfaces and reboot your machine to make all services aware of the new metric:

```
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex <INDEX_OF_VPN_IF> -InterfaceMetric 1
```

## Explanation

Windows 10 uses the [Automatic Metric feature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/automatic-metric-for-ipv4-routes) to determine the metric of each network interface automatically. You might expect, that Windows uses the metric just for routing purposes, but it also uses it to select the primary DNS server. You can read more about this in [this excellent answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1010660/536173).

In my case, a metric of 55 was assigned to my virtual VPN interface, 50 to my physical WiFi interface and 5 to my physical Ethernet interface. You can check the current metrics with the following PowerShell command:

```
Get-NetIPInterface | Select-Object -Property InterfaceIndex, InterfaceAlias, InterfaceMetric
```

I then changed the metric of my virtual VPN interface to `1`:

```
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex <INDEX_OF_VPN_IF> -InterfaceMetric 1
```

The change was visible with `Get-NetIPInterface` immediately, but the services did not seem to be aware of that change already. After a reboot, everything worked as expected. The VPN interface with its DNS server was highest priority and I did not suffer a DNS leak anymore.

It might not be 100% stable though, as the other DNS servers are still available and will be chosen, if the DNS server of VPN connection does not answer in time.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a command script to modify the DNS servers on your leaking interface.

I.e., if your physical interface is named "Ethernet" and its IP is statically configured with DNS statically confgured, then run a command script as administrator with this line:

```
netsh dnsclient delete dnsserver "Ethernet" all
```

You will get a message

```
There are no Domain Name Servers (DNS) configured on this computer.
```

perhaps, or maybe you just get that in my case where I only have the one. When I tried this on a DHCP config for this interface, the DNS server was set by DHCP when I removed the static one. Windows really wants you to have a DNS server.

After your VPN is up. See if you get leaks then.
Before you tear down your VPN, add back your DNS server to the interface with

```
netsh dnsclient add dnsserver "Ethernet" 192.168.1.1 (for example)
```

Comment: On my physical NIC, I use DHCP. Is there still a way to remove the DNS config?

Comment: I don't find a way so far: https://superuser.com/q/1658597/1077440

Comment: No reason why you can't use a static IP and static DNS. If you manage the DHCP server, just set up a reservation for your device's MAC address. If you don't manage the DHCP server, then you'll have to get an IP address assignment via DHCP first, then you can just configure yourself to use that IP statically.

Comment: Consider the network an unsecure puplic WiFi without access to the DHCP server. Yeah, I could write a script that reads the current lease and convert it into static settings without DNS. And I could automate this with the task scheduler, triggered by hopefully existing Shrew Soft events. But to be honest, that's quite hacky and might lead to duplicate IP addresses. I'm in favor of a more stable solution. Furthermore, I am not sure if an established VPN connection will survive the change from DHCP to static. Layer 3 will flap for sure in this moment.